# Adding quotes at start and end

Tags: vim

I have a list of dates in a .txt file:

```
11/05/2017
12/05/2017
15/05/2017
16/05/2017
17/05/2017
```

I need to add a quote before and after them and end each line with a semicolon instead of a space.

My output should be:

```
'11/05/2017'; '12/05/2017';'15/05/2017'; '16/05/2017'; '17/05/2017'
```

How do I get this in Vim?

Answer (score 4):

Replace the text with regex, then join the lines.

```
:%s/\(.*\)/'\1';
```

Then `ggVG` to select all, then `J` to join the lines.

Update: As @pbogut mentioned in the comment, you can do this at once with this regex:

```
:%s/\(.*\)\n/'\1';_
```

Note that I added `_` instead of (space) as it is not visible. You should use space instead.

Comment: You can also `%s/\(.*\)\n/'\1'; ` and you can skip `ggVG` part as it will replace new lines as well.

Comment: @pbogut That looks better as it can do everything at once. I added that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do everything in one `:substitute` by matching the newline.

```
%s/\v(.{-})\n/'\1';
```

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of "{-}"

Comment: @user2571881. Sure. This means "as few characters as possible, but at much as needed" in this context. IIRC `:h /\{-}`. BTW as I've used `\v` the pattern is in _very magic_ syntax

Answer (score 0):

usually macro will beat ex command in vimgolf. ;)

(assume your cursor is on first line):

```
0qqi'<ESC>A'; <ESC>Jq
```

then

```
99@q
```

To replay.

Or using recursive macro to avoid the `99`

Oh, after that there would be a `;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool plugin that can surround the statement in quotes.  It is called Surround.Vim.  http://vimawesome.com/plugin/surround-vim.  As far as the second part I would write a macro to remove the line break at the end of the line and add a semicolon.  You can run macros on multiple lines at once.  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros.  I hope this helps.  Let me know if you have any questions.